# What am I doing wrong ? Google adsense application got rejected 3 times, reason "Page type"

Tags: google-adsense

What am I doing wrong ? Google adsense application got rejected 3 times, reason "Page type".

I am running blog http://photoforu.blogspot.com/ from sometime, but able to approve the adsense account for it, the issue they say is

Issues:
- Page type

---

Further detail:

Page type: Your website is a type of website that we do not currently
accept into our program. Such websites include, but are not limited to,
chat sites, sites that drive traffic through cybersquatting, and sites
that use excessive keywords in the content or code of their pages.

---

I don't understand whats wrong with the content,
Google webmaster tools don't show any error.. and there are only 82 keywords yet.

What am I doing wrong ?

List of keywords: (for reference only)

1. image (3 variants)
2. love (4 variants)
3. post (2 variants)
4. blog (3 variants)
5. baby (2 variants)
6. photoforu
7. girls
8. new (2 variants)
9. blogspot
10. fashion
11. car (2 variants)
12. cute
13. photo (2 variants)
14. funny
15. google
16. share
17. india (2 variants)
18. beauty
19. photograph (2 variants)
20. beautiful

...loads more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because all you're doing is copy-and-pasting articles from other sites without even citing the source. That's called plagiarism and copyright infringement.

Try submitting your site when you actually have original content to post. Otherwise it just looks like you're creating a spam blog solely for the purpose of generating adwords revenue without actually providing any value to visitors.

Comment: Hmm, Can you please explain some thing about the "even citing the source. That's called plagiarism and copyright infringement.", I know lots of site (mostly news sites and blogs) those usually copy the content from each other just with minor editing, how do the got it approved for them. Many Many site only read the rss feeds and provide the content, many just crawl the page and open them in iframe..

Comment: Chetan: RSS feeds are a legitimate way to syndicate content. They are provided by the original publishers, and the feed items link back to the original articles. Even blogs that post aggregate news from other sources will cite the original source and link to it. You've done none of that. And even if you did, your site looks spammy, has poor content, and has spammy fake comments throughout it. I don't think you'll ever be accepted into Adsense,  as you've made no attempt to provide anything of value to visitors.

Comment: Furthermore, the fundamental problem here is your attitude and motivation. Anyone who tries to pass off such a low quality site as revenue-worthy is either seriously deluded or thinks visitors are too stupid to see that you're just peddling garbage with minimal effort made to dress it up. That's not an attitude conducive to running a successful website; it's the attitude of a spammer. Don't create a website unless you have something to contribute to the online community. Otherwise you may as well try to eBay your pocket lint or ketchup packets.

Comment: Thanks Lesa for your reply, I didn't have any intension of being spammer or what so ever, It is my hobbie blog, and i am only indexing my favorite images that i search from web + some of the articles that i like, But thanks for all of your suggestion, I'll try to improve the content quality and stop posting garbage. Can you please provide me so tips. I'll Very thankful.

Comment: Somehow I doubt that, given all the suspicious "anonymous" comments on your blog entries. But if this genuinely is a hobby, and you're not just trying to make a quick buck, then I would suggest pushing money out of your mind for now. Read books and articles on how to write (not how to write sales or marketing copy, or how to write for SEO, just how to write good quality content that people will enjoy reading). Then _if_ your blog starts attracting visitors on its own, you can start thinking about monetizing your blog, and you'll be able to get into Adsense.

Answer (score 1):

Google Adsense approval depends upon many things. Its not only about how and how many keywords you use. Also, it has been observed by people that reason of rejection of application is not always correct.

As I think, you might have copied content from other sites. Google Adsense terms clearly states that they wont accept copy-righted content. That might be the problem. Also, Traffic!!! High traffic is needed. (Your location matter too. if you are in India or China, you have to post at least 50-60 posts and drive good amount traffic in six months.)

Try following things:

- Upload genuine content.
- Never post copy-righted content.
- Content should be relevant(Check your titles and links)
- Only using keywords is not enough. Keywords must be used for relevant content. Also, use specific keywords instead of very general.(ex. use "Photos of babies" instead of "photos")
- Try driving more n more traffic, that too by genuine ways. (If you are telling your friends and some group of people to click more more on your website to show increased traffic, forget Adsense. Never ever do that!).
- Use Google Analytics and Google Web-master tools before applying.

Read the policies and guidelines:

- [AdSense Terms and Conditions](http://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms)
- [AdSense Programme Policies](http://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182)
- Google Webmaster Guidelines - support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769
- Eligibility to participate in AdSense - support.google.com/adsense/answer/9724
- Prohibited content - support.google.com/adsense/answer/1348688